# procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `execute sp_executesql` to execute a insert query in sp. Query executed, insert happen properly. After that I am using `scope indentity()`, value is set into one output para. But I am getting error:

> `procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.`

How to solve it? Does anybody having an idea?

Comment: We'd need to see the code to be sure, but it sounds like the last statement before the attempt to access `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` wasn't an insert to a table with an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: An output parameter is different to the return value.

Answer (score 1):

The `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function returns the last identity value inserted **in the current scope**. The dynamic query you are executing with `EXEC sp_executesql` is *not* in the current scope. You need to call `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in your dynamic query or use a different method to achieve the result you want.

Here's how you could use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`:

```
DECLARE @ID int;

EXEC sp_executesql N'
  INSERT INTO …;
  SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
', N'@ID int OUTPUT', @ID OUTPUT;

RETURN @ID;
```

Or you could try the following:

```
DECLARE @LastID TABLE (ID int);

INSERT INTO @LastID (ID)
EXEC  sp_executesql N'
  INSERT INTO …;
  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
';

RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @LastID);
```

If you are on SQL Server 2005+, you could modify the above method to use the `OUTPUT` clause of `INSERT` instead of `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Comment: Thanks Andriy, for ur help.I done same but instead of variable,I have taken output parameter.But it is not working.I wrote scope_identity() inside the sp_executesql